# Magento Popular Search Results - How to get them to do 301 redirects when setting a redirect in Admin

Tags: magento, mage

It LOOKS like I tracked down an issue I'm having with magento popular search results, but I'm going nuts trying to get them to redirect properly.

OK, here's the situation.  I don't mind Magento's popular search results queries in the SE's index.  Alot of times, the customer inputs something that can be helpful for search.  My problem is when a customer types into the search bar the exact same terms as a category or products.  This creates duplicate content issues, so I redirect these query terms in the Magento Admin.

However, these redirects are 302 temporary redirects, when they really should be 301.

I tracked down a file in Mage > CatalogSearch > controllers > ResultController.php that has the following code on line 65

```
if ($query->getRedirect()){
                $query->save();
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($query->getRedirect());                    
                return;
            }
```

I think that somewhere here, there should be a 
->setHttpResponseCode(301)

But so far, I can't get a 301 redirect response anywhere.

I can certainly do this in htaccess, but it would be a lot easier if set programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure, that the `if` block really is being entered, this one should work:

```
if ($query->getRedirect()){
    $query->save();
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($query->getRedirect(), 301);                    
    return;
}
```

I assume that `$this->getResponse()` contains an `Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http` instance. See its superclass method `Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract::setRedirect()`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to define permanent redirects using the backend, goto `Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management -> Edit URL Rewrite -> Redirect -> Permanent (301)`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that you can specify some redirects in the ADMIN section, but those are usually reserved for products and categories, right?  Or if you need to redirect on the fly?

Comment: @Robert: I tested `setRedirect($query->getRedirect(), 301);` with inner and outer domain redirects. It worked like a charme, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Robert: yes, you'll usually see products and categories in URL rewrite management, but there's a 3rd option `Custom` which allows you define your own redirects. I only mentioned URL rewrite managment as an alternative, though. I assumed you already have or plan to extend `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query` by a http_code field, or another flag that allows you to decide when to 302, and when to 301 on matching a specific search term.

Comment: the code did in fact work like a charm.  However, it did not work in the local folder as I'm accustomed to using when customizing Magento.  Just to test, I did it in the base code in the Mage folder, and it does work.  Either I did not replicate the path correctly in the code > local folder, or something else is going on.